# maven project not working on websphere application server

Tags: maven, spring-mvc

i created a spring project in maven.when i run it on tomcat server then it runnig but when i deployed it on IBM websphere application server then it is not running and showing following error 
Error 404: java.io.FileNotFoundException: SRVE0190E: File not found: /payment/pay
how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

We also faced the same issue when deploying to IBM Webshpere. The main reason behind that was while startup Spring and other jar was not getting recognized as by default all the jar are inside the resource folder and can be referenced from there but while startup Webshpere look for any dependencies in the WebShpere Shared Library.
 Few things that we did were

1. Change the pom.xml to add the was 8.5.5 dependency.
2. configured maven build as below.

{

```
{<build>
        <sourceDirectory>src\main\java</sourceDirectory>
        <outputDirectory>WEB-INF\classes</outputDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <webappDirectory>src\main\webapp</webappDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

}

3. Setting up Shared Library in Websphere console and keeping all the jar in there.

We were using Spring Boot.

Hope this will help.